# Azure service for hosting zip file securely

Tags: spring-boot, azure, cassandra, azure-keyvault, datastax-astra

I am running a spring boot app which internally uses secure bundle zip file of size 13kb . I want to host the file to remote server securely and encrypted . The infrastructure I am in is azure . Which azure service I can use to host my zip file securely ? Can I use **azure key value** to access my zip file ?

Comment: this link will help you--https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the Zip file in **Azure Blob storage**.  Azure Storage uses server-side encryption (SSE) to automatically encrypt your data when it is persisted to the cloud. You can configure your storage account to accept requests from secure connections only by setting the `Secure transfer required` property for the storage account.

You could then restrict access to the storage blob via Shared Access Signature.

If you wanted to be *extra secret squirrel*, you could even enable CMK (Customer Managed Keys) for the encryption to make doubly sure nobody is looking at your secret sauce.

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-require-secure-transfer
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/customer-managed-keys-configure-key-vault?tabs=portal
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/security-recommendations

Answer (score 1):

You could theoretically host your zip file in Key Vault if you serialize it to a text file.  But I think that's a bad idea.

The right service is Azure Storage File Share.